# What card game is this

Tags: identify-this-game, solitaire

I used to play this 2 player card game with my nan when I was young, and was told it was called Chinese patience, but looking it up online I don't think it's correct, and I can't find anything like it. Any ideas?

You start by dealing all cards face down to both players, but as you are dealing you randomly put 4 cards face up along a row at the top of the table. The aim of the game is to get rid of all your cards, and the first to do so wins. You take it in turns, and on your turn you're trying to put cards on any of the 4 cards up top, usual solitaire rules apply there so if there is a red 7 it needs to be a black 6. If you have an ace, that goes to one side and that becomes an additional place you can get rid of cards, but in the usual sequence of needing the 2 next. If you can't go, you place your unused card face up next to your pile.

If the other player notices you missed something, you can then knock on the table, you then have to miss a turn, so you always need to pay attention! Another rule is that you can put cards on the opponents discarded pile if you have one that continues a sequence, so your 5 of hearts can go on their discarded 4 of hearts.

So that's about it. Anyone know what this might be called? Hoping my nan hasn't just completely made it up!

Thanks!